# Java 8 parse ZonedDateTime from string not containing all fields

Tags: java, time

When I have only year (and possibly several other temporal fields) specified in a string pattern, I would like the other absent fields to be set to their lowest values. For example, prior to Java 8 my code looked like

```
String source = "2015";
String pattern = "yyyy";
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = null;
try {
    date = sdf.parse(source);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

SimpleDateFormat sdfGMT2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss z");
sdfGMT2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

String newf = sdfGMT2.format(date);
System.out.println(newf);
```

which returns me `2015.01.01 00:00:00 GMT`

However, in `java.time` formatter returns a `TemporalAccessor`; the code below throws exception

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY");
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2008", fmt);
```

Exception:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2008' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain
    ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2008},ISO
        of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

How do I achieve the same result with Java 8 time API as I did with older API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit more verbose, but you have to specify the default values for missing fields when creating your [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
        .toFormatter()
        .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);

ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2008", fmt);
```

This includes the [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) which is necessary for a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

Comment: should I `.appendPattern("YYYY")`?

Comment: That is what the `appendValue()` is doing above. But if you would rather use `appendPattern()` you should use [`yyyy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#YEAR) instead of [`YYYY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#weekBasedYear--)

Comment: Yes, `YYYY` causes exception. Thanks, that helped! I will ask another question in a separate thread and I welcome you to help me :)

Comment: By the way, do you know how to find out whether month was actually parsed or not (was it present in string pattern)?

Comment: It is a pity... seems like this approach does not work for arbitrary string patterns (since I do not know the pattern in advance). For example, using `.appendPattern("yyyy DDD")` I should remove `.parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1)
.parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)`